# Image position varies in different layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am overlapping `relativelayout` in `recyclerAdapter` using item decorator. The problem is overlapping varies in different mobile screens. How can i resolve it.

Below is the class i'm using to overlap the layouts.

```
    public class OverlapDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final static int vertOverlap = -300;

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets (Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        if (position == 0) {

            outRect.set(0, 0, 0, 0);

        } else {
            outRect.set(0, vertOverlap, 0, 0);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: You need to convert -300 pixel to dp so position will be same in all device

Comment: its an integer value where i convert it..?

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can declare static method in your Utility calss like::

```
public static float convertPixelsToDp(int px){
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, myPixels, displaymetrics );
    }
```

And in your code:

```
outRect.set(0, Your_Utility_Class.convertPixelsToDp(-300), 0, 0);
```

Comment: after converting to pixel overlapping does not works